# Webkitdotnet Pagesetting.margin set error

Tags: vb.net, webkit.net

i am new in vb and i dont understand the error,
this code uses webkitdotnet and i made a browser and i want to change print pagesetting margin values.

code is,

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebKitBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost:78/print/printer.asp")
    WebKitBrowser1.PageSettings.Margins(set="5, 5, 5, 5")


End Sub
```

end the error is

```
Property access must assign to the property or use its value.
```

How can i set new page margins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With WebKitBrowser1.PageSettings.Margins
        .Bottom = 5
        .Left = 5
        .Top = 5
        .Right = 5
End With
```